# Blender's features missed in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, visualization, blender

I am designing a particle physics visualization where electron accelerates in a hole and multiplies in many other electrons in a high electric field through avalanche. 
I know that Blender has adequate tools for this visualization such as blurring and some other features.

I however would like to do such an visualization with Gnuplot where I can use AWK inside and add a background picture like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30102008/54964).

However, I am unsure about other features which I will miss if I use Gnuplot.

How can you substitute Blender with Gnuplot?

Comment: _Gnuplot_ and _Blender_ are rather different kind of program. Maybe you can want to use [povray](http://www.povray.org/) and a batch script. BTW which kind of data do you have to do the [shower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_shower_%28physics%29)?

Comment: @hastur first generated, just random motion. After e- stream above 60keV field.

Comment: I do not imagine what are you searching to represent (it can help to formulate an answer more complex than _These are 2 different programs_): usually in showers' picture there are shown: a) the particle tracks and the couple (_e+e-_...)  creation points; b) the probability to find and electron (in different colors);  c) somehow related, the speed of the electrons  d) the  probability of decay e) the field strength and/or direction...
I continue to see it as a work for povray :)

Comment: Feel free to make your comment an snswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender and Gnuplot are rather different kind of program.

From Blender's site you can read

> It supports the entirety of the 3D pipeline—modeling, rigging, animation, simulation, rendering, compositing and motion tracking, even video editing and game creation. Advanced users employ Blender’s API for Python scripting to customize the application and write specialized tools; often these are included in Blender’s future releases.

Gnuplot instead

> is a portable command-line driven graphing utility

really cosy;  you can create scientific plots, perfect for `Latex/pdf/eps` and scientific publications or thesis.

It is not able to do any 3d rendering as instead [povray](http://www.povray.org)

> The Persistence of Vision Raytracer is a high-quality, Free Software tool for creating stunning three-dimensional graphics.

*Povray* and *gnuplot* can quick take advantage of *bash/awk programming*.

Comment: How to put visual effects ect shadowing to povray after generation? In photoshop? But how well with 3d objects?

Comment: You will put shadows etc __in__ the generation script not after. Check the tutorial files. You will finish to love it. :)